# Hexadeicimal data and corresponding MySQL field type

Tags: mysql, node.js

I used some Node.js code to stream a file image before inserting it to the database. I have a problem inserting the data into the related MySQL table field. So I run `console.log(streamedFileContent)` on the server to see what is this data about and I got this:

```
<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 03 9e 00 00 03 52 08 06 00 00 00 0d a5 11 28 00 00 00 04 73 42 49 54 08 08 08 08 7\
c 08 64 88 00 ... 150808 more bytes>
```

What should be the appropriate MySQL field type for this data?

Comment: [The BINARY and VARBINARY Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)

Comment: I used binary type but the insertion always fails, this is really mysterious. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: *I used binary type but the insertion always fails* You must show both table's DDL and the code which you use for insertion. Edit your question.

Comment: I have posted the related code on StackOverflow so that this does not look like cross posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375522/why-insertion-fails-into-a-mysql-binary-field

Comment: No problems, wait until someone helps you on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is textual language. So you must convert your binary data to its textual representation (solid hexadecimal codes, for example, 'MySQL' -> '4D7953514C') and use it while building query text or attaching text parameter, and use [UNHEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) function over this value in query text for to reconstruct binary value on the server side.

Avoid exceeding the `max_packet_size` value for your query text, increase it if needed in MySQL configuration file. Remember - textual representation is 2 times longer than binary one.

If the file which you want to insert into the table is local for your MySQL server you can use [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function.

Comment: If your binary data is over 255 bytes use some of [BLOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) datatypes. Select proper datatype according to max possible size of your data. See [String Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings). It seems MEDIUMBLOB (16Mb max) is enough in your case...

Comment: @Begueradj It seems the only variant for you is to create text type column (something like `table.text("photo", "MEDIUMTEXT")`), serialize your data during insertion on the client side, and de-serialise back during selection (for example, there exists `atob()` and `btoa()` functions).

Comment: I tested what it comes to storing the data. I will investigate later more about the serialization and desirialization, I should have kissed you if you were here :) Thank you very much. I do not understand why someone downvoted your effort to help me

Comment: And it is amazing what I found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html): it says `longtext` is the same as `longblob`. I am really happy for this because  I wanted to see if I can create a blob type in Knex.js using the `specificType` method. Thank you a lot again

Comment: @Begueradj *it says longtext is the same as longblob.* That's right when you set `binary` charset and collation to longtext field explicitly. If not, your data may be damaged. Be carefully.

Comment: Exactly. I have just been reading that link and I found out how  data is stored is not exactly the same way. Thank you very much for the attention, that shows you are really professional, other people do not care at all.

Comment: @Begueradj - Is this the "same" that you are referring to?  "These correspond to the four BLOB types and have the same maximum lengths and storage requirements."